# GA4 Cross Domain Tracking - Segment traffic depending on which domain the user first arrived

Tags: cross-domain, reporting, google-analytics-4

I'm currently implementing Cross Domain Tracking (GA4) for a customer and everything works fine.
It's the HR page of a multi and there are several landingpages for each company, however the recruiting is all done trough one page on the headquarters page. Let's call the subsidiaries Company A and B and the main "company Z". Users would arrive at the pages of "company A and B" through ADS and so on, however recruiting would happen on "company z's" homepage.

I need to create reports that shows information for each subsidiary. How can I for example create segments that only includes sessions that began on the page of "company A".

Or further, filter only on events that occurred for users that arrived at the page of "company A"

Searching for Cross Domain unfortunately brings up only an enormous amount of guides how to implement it, but not how to analyse the surrounding data.